# Application works but the first controller inside it fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm setting up a controller in my application (loosely following [a guide](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-scopes.html)). The first divs behave as expected - the first one shows the text and the other is empty. However, *ContraAss* controller seems not to be rendered and only shows *{{info}}*. What stupid thing am I missing? (NB. I'm sure it's something basic but given lack of experience and general irritation over intellisense not performing well, I'm out of ideas how to proceed.)

XML

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="ApplicationHolder">
    <div>Uno: "{{holderUno}}"</div>
    <div>Duo: "{{holderDuo}}"</div>
    <div ng-controller="ContraAss">{{info}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var application = angular.module("ApplicationHolder", []);

application.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.holderUno = "Blipp";
});

application.controller("ContrAss", function($scope) {
  $scope.info = "This is an info carrier";
});
```

Output

> Uno: "Blipp"
>   Duo: ""
>   {{info}}

First I thought that I might be sending the scope in an incorrect way but then I realized that it'd be rendered as an empty string, akin with the *HolderDuo*. So now, I lean towards a suspicion that the controller isn't recognized as a controller at all.

How should I handle it?

Comment: Not sure if it's an example typo, but I see a mismatch between `ContraAss` in your XML and `ContrAss` in your JS

Comment: @Starscream1984 Donkey poo! 1. Post it as a reply so I can accept the answer. 2. This is not humanly acceptable - I want my intellisense thinking for me! I checked for typos for at least 15 minutes. Grrrr....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch (typo) between the controller name in your HTML and JS.

The HTML is looking for a controller called `ContraAss`, but in your JavaScript you have defined it as `ContrAss`. Ergo, no controller exists and it will throw an error into your console (which is a good first place to check whenever you don't understand what JavaScript is doing).

Change your controller definition to:

```
myApp.controller("ContraAss", function($scope) {
  $scope.info = "This is an info carrier";
});
```

Comment: +1 for the (kind of obvious now, which is a bit embarrassing) hint on checking the console. It was right there - in flying, red, highlighted colors. But I forgot to check it. Shame on me...   :(

Comment: You will get in the habit as you work with Angular :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated controller name as suggested by @Starscream1984 in comments from `ContraAss` to `ContrAss` (and changed the app name to myApp):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div>Uno: "{{holderUno}}"</div>
    <div>Duo: "{{holderDuo}}"</div>
    <div ng-controller="ContrAss">{{info}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.holderUno = "Blipp";
});

myApp.controller("ContrAss", function($scope) {
  $scope.info = "This is an info carrier";
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/HB7LU/19922/

Comment: Oh, I didn't know one could fiddle Angular stuff. +1 for the example. (If the original discoverer of the typo doesn't post a reply himself, I'll green-check you, as well. Very honest referral.)